# Getting an System.OutOfMemoryException when bulk updating Exif Metadata in an image catalog

Tags: c#

I have written some code using System.Windows.Media.Imaging to update the keyword properties of jpeg images in a folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8pDU.png)

The code works, but often (critically not all the time) I get an out of memory exception after processing approximately 70 images, at which point the program is consuming around 4Gb of memory. Occasionally (one run in 20 perhaps) the program will process thousands of images without every running out of memory. The main code is :

```
jpeg = new JpegMetadataAdapter(fullPath);
ReadOnlyCollection<string> newKeyWords = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(*lots of space separated words here*);
jpeg.Metadata.Keywords = newKeyWords;
jpeg.Save();


  public JpegMetadataAdapter(string path)
         {
            this.path = path;
            frame = getBitmapFrame(path);
            Metadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata.Clone();
         }

  private BitmapFrame getBitmapFrame(string path)
         {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
               decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

               imageFrame = decoder.Frames[0];
               decoder = null;
            }
            return imageFrame;
         }
```

The exception stack trace looks like this:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
  HResult=0x8007000E
  Message=Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
  Source=PresentationCore
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CreateCachedBitmap(BitmapFrame frame, BitmapSourceSafeMILHandle wicSource, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, BitmapPalette palette)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.FinalizeCreation()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode..ctor(Int32 frameNumber, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, BitmapDecoder decoder)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupFrames(BitmapDecoder decoder, ReadOnlyCollection`1 frames)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Initialize(BitmapDecoder decoder)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder..ctor(Stream bitmapStream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid expectedClsId)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapDecoder..ctor(Stream bitmapStream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption)
   at ImageMetaData.MetaDataManager.JpegMetadataAdapter.getBitmapFrame(String path) in E:\GitHub\Shaneinsweden\ImageMeta\ImageMeta\ImageMetaData\MetaDataManager.cs:line 266
   at ImageMetaData.MetaDataManager.JpegMetadataAdapter..ctor(String path) in E:\GitHub\Shaneinsweden\ImageMeta\ImageMeta\ImageMetaData\MetaDataManager.cs:line 223
   at ImageMetaData.MetaDataManager.UpdateFolderImagesMetadata(String imageFolder, String keyWordFile) in E:\ImageMeta\ImageMetaData\MetaDataManager.cs:line 146
   at ImageMeta.UnitTest1.UpdateCatalog() in E:\GitHub\Shaneinsweden\ImageMeta\ImageMeta\ImageMeta\UnitTest1.cs:line 22
```

Looking at the memory changes using diagnostic tool snapshots I can see that the objects that are increasing in number are Filestreams

Comment: Chances are you're not disposing of an `IDisposable` you're creating. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Yeah I should be able to do that

Comment: [Github repo shaneinsweden/ImageMetaMin](https://github.com/shaneinsweden/ImageMetaMin)

Contains a minimum solution which demonstrates the problem. To run the solution look at the readme file

Comment: or follow these instructions:

1. If you have already run the solution (so that some files have metatdata) delete the files from the images2 folder and copy the original images (without metadata) from images folder into the images2 folder
2. Edit the file ImageMetaTests.cs so that the paths to the imagefolder (images2) and the metadatafile Images2-s1.csv match the actual path on your computer.
3. Run in debug mode the unit test UpdateCatalog() in the ImageMetaTests.cs file when you run it in debug you can see the memory increasing over time

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of solution that sometimes works just forcing garbage collection before opening a new FileStream in my code I changed from

```
   public JpegMetadataAdapter(string path)
         {
            this.path = path;
            frame = getBitmapFrame(path);
            Metadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata.Clone();
         }
```

To

```
       public JpegMetadataAdapter(string path)
             {
                this.path = path;
-->             GC.Collect();
                frame = getBitmapFrame(path);
                Metadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata.Clone();
             }
```

After doing that the memory usage stayed fixed at around 100Mb instead of growing to 13Gb.

Comment: You never need to call GC.Collect ever, something else is wrong in the code. you can use Visual Studio's shortcut ALT + F2 and look for what objects are floating around and where they were created from

Comment: Thanks for that - I am aware that you should never need to call garbage collection . also if you look at the text I had actually written you would read that the objects floating around have been identified and are filestreams. You can also see that from the code that the filestreams are contained within a using statement, yet are not disposed of - thus my desperation tactics in nudging the garbage collector.

Something must be holding a reference to the filestreams to prevent their garbage collection - HOWEVER - as I also said sometimes (around 10% of the time)  the error doesnt happen